Как сделать элемент в unity со списком, в котором можно клавишами переключаться между ними?
Есть у меня настройки в игре и я хочу добавить смену языка. Саму смену я сделаю, но я хочу сделать не совсем обычный ui элемент. 
Вот так мне надо. Когда мы выделяем это элемент, нажатием, условно стрелок у нас бы менялся язык.

Переключение между элементами UI, это Navigation Options, которые можно видеть в всех базовых элементах типа кнопки или слайдера.
